# Как работают каналы Go

Tags: golang

Недавно начал изучать Go. На данный момент изучаю каналы. У меня вопрос, почему в этой программе значение в канал передается:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func f (c chan string){
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}

func main() {
    //r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    c := make(chan string)

    go f(c)

    //text, _ := r.ReadString('\n')
    //fmt.Println(text)
    fmt.Println("Hello")
    c <- "jhj"
}
```

А в этой нет

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func f (c chan string){
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}

func main() {
    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    c := make(chan string)

    go f(c)

    text, _ := r.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(text)
    //fmt.Println("Hello")
    c <- "text"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле значение в канал передается в обоих случаях. То, что вы наблюдаете, является классической гонкой (race condition).

Вы запускаете функцию `f` в отдельной горутине, которая блокируется на чтение из канала `c`. Как только вы записываете в канал какую-либо строку (`jhj` в первом случае и `text` во втором), функция разблокируется и продолжает выполнение. Проблема в том, что `main` тоже продолжает выполнение после записи в канал параллельно с функцией `f` на другом ядре процессора и успевает завершится до того, как выполнится `fmt.Println` в функции `f`. Но это никак не гарантируется и поэтому и называется гонкой.

Более того, даже исполнение на одном процессорном ядре не гарантирует, что функция `fmt.Println` внутри `f` выполнится раньше, чем завершится `main`. Как правильно заметил @Ainar-G, вам нужно добавить синхронизацию и дождаться завершения `f`. Вот один из вариантов как это можно сделать:

```go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func f(c chan string) {
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    // сигнализируем о завершении функции
    // по сути делаем wg.Add(-1)
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    c := make(chan string)

    wg.Add(1) // говорим что будем дожидаться завершения одной функции
    go f(c)

    text, _ := r.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(text)
    c <- "text"
    // ждем завершения функции f
    // Wait вернется, когда счетчик внутри wg станет равным 0
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ни ваш первый, ни второй вариант не даёт гарантий работы.  Всё потому
что ваш `main` не ждёт выполнения работы.  Добавьте
синхронизацию между `f` и `main`.  Самое
примитивное — добавить в конец функции
`main` код `select{}`, который заблокирует
выполнение `main`.